# AJAX $.post works in View, but will not work when placed in a .js file. All other JQuery works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC in general, as well as JQuery and AJAX and I have come across a strange issue.

I have finished my first run-through of building a practice website and the past few days I devoted my time to adding JQuery's and such to make the site more interactive.

Today I finished all my JQuerys and everything works great so I decided to clean it all out of the View and just put them into a script.js file in the Scripts folder of MVC.

Inserted into the View as `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Employees.js")`

However when I do this anything in regards to AJAX does not work.

Now this only entails two mini-snippets of code that interact with the controller to either Edit or Save a change, but everything else works great! Even the edit and save JQuerys that make menus and other UI changes all work just fine, but the actual `$.post` to update the change does not work.

Here are the two snippets of code that sit within functions of JQuery that all work just fine.

```
$.post(
'@Url.Action("customEdit", "Employee")',
{
    'id': newID,
    'name': newName,
    'birth': newDate
},
function (data) { },
"json"
);
```

and

```
$.post(
'@Url.Action("customDelete", "Employee")',
{
    'id': newID
},
function (data) { },
"json"
);
```

and again, if I move the entire script literally back into the View it works just great! So I am confused as to why moving it to a .js suddenly makes only these two little snippets not work.

There is no re-ordering of code, it re-inserts exactly where it was before.

For an overview here is my entire `<script>`.

```
 $(function () {
        $("td[colspan=12]").find("p").hide();
        $("td[colspan=12]").addClass("nopadding");

        $("tr").click(function (e) {
            if (!$(e.target).is('button') && !$(e.target).is('input')) {
                var $target = $(this);
                var $detailsTd = $target.find("td[colspan=12]");
                if ($detailsTd.length) {
                    $detailsTd.find("p").slideUp();
                    $detailsTd.addClass("nopadding");
                } else {
                    $detailsTd = $target.next().find("td[colspan=12]");
                    $detailsTd.find("p").slideToggle();
                    $detailsTd.toggleClass("nopadding");
                    $detailsTd.stopPropagation();
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function editFunction(element) {

        $(element).closest("span").hide();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-save-button").show();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").hide();


        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
            .hide()
            .next("span.item-field")
            .show();

        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
            .hide()
            .next("span.item-field")
            .show();

    }

function saveFunction(element) {
    var one = $(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-field").find(":input:first").val();
    var two = $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-field").find(":input:first").val();

    if (one == "" || two == "") {

        if (one == "") {
            alert("invalid name");
        }
        if (two == "") {
            alert("invalid birthday");
        }

    } else {

        $(element).closest("span").hide();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-edit-button").show();
        $(element).closest("td").find("span.item-delete-button").show();

        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display").html($(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-field").find(":input:first").val());
        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
            .show()
            .next("span.item-field")
            .hide();

        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display").html($(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-field").find(":input:first").val());
        $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display")
            .show()
            .next("span.item-field")
            .hide();

        var newID = $(element).closest("td").find("span.ID").text();
        var newDate = $(element).closest("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display").text();
        var newName = $(element).closest("td").prev("td").prev("td").find("span.item-display").text();

        $.post(
            '@Url.Action("customEdit", "Employee")',
             {
                 'id': newID,
                 'name': newName,
                 'birth': newDate
             },
            function (data) { },
            "json"
        );

    }
}

function deleteStart(element) {
    $(element).closest("table").toggleClass("table-hover");
    $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'red');
}

function deleteStopped(element) {
    $(element).closest("table").toggleClass("table-hover");
    $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'initial');
}

function deleteFunction(element) {
    var newID = $(element).closest("td").find("span.ID").text();
    console.log(newID);
    $('#'+newID).removeClass('fade');
    $('#' + newID).modal('hide');
    $(element).closest("table").toggleClass("table-hover");
    $(element).closest("tr").next("tr").remove();
    $(element).closest("tr").remove();
    $.post(
'@Url.Action("customDelete", "Employee")',
{
    'id': newID
},
function (data) { },
"json"
);
    $(element).closest("tr").css('background-color', 'initial');
}
```

Sooo yea, EVERYTHING works just as before, even the Save and Edit interactions (row updates, modals, ect..) but the actual `$.post` does not work (controller isn't even hit in Debug). Yet if I just re-insert all the code back into the View it works.

Any and all help appreciated! :)

Comment: The Razor view engine doesn't touch .js files. The literal string  `@Url.Action("customDelete", "Employee")` is the request url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put your Javascript in a view, Razor rendering engine will resolve the following line to appropriate URL:

```
'@Url.Action("customDelete", "Employee")'
```

But `.js` files do not get rendered by the view engine, so the above line stays the same which is not a URL.

Comment: Ah I see. Is there a simple way to remedy this?

Comment: Simple way would be to put your actual URL in the `.js` file. See what that line gets rendered to when you put the javascript in the view and paste that then in your `.js` file.

Comment: Okay, so I want to try and find the entire $.post' surl or just the Actions' url? DO you happen to know of an example I could look at? I am still quite new to all of this stuff haha

Comment: You just need to replace that line `'@Url.Action("customDelete", "Employee")'` with whatever gets rendered when the javascript is in the view. It will probably look something like: `'/Employee/customDelete'`. Use dev tools in your browser, or just plain old "view source" to find what the line is rendered into.

Comment: I. Love. You. That is all :) *will award answer when timer is expired*

Comment: @Floremin As an alternative to hard coding the url... consider what triggers your AJAX. If you use a form use the `action` attribute and let Razor resolve your url on the view page -- then capture this with javascript; If it is an anchor tag use `href`; If it is an other element use a custom `data-url` attribute; Etc. Don't forget to disable the default browser action `event.preventDefault()` when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The JS file is not being parsed by the rendering engine, only your views are. So you'll need to save those URL's from Razor as JS variables in the main view.

Place this in your main view:

```
<script>var action_custom_delete = '@Url.Action("customDelete", "Employee")';</script>
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Employees.js")
```

Now you can use the variable *action_custom_delete* in the JS file wherever you need the URL.